# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load dialect 'org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration

Tags: drools, drools-kie-server

while i am using

```
KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
kbuilder.add(xlsRes, ResourceType.DRL);
```

I am getting the below error in weblogic. The same is working fine in standalone application while i am running in eclipse.
    I am using
    Java8
    drools 6.1.0
    weblogic12c

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load dialect 'org.drools.rule.builder.dial
ect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration:java:org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.Java
DialectConfiguration'
        at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.ad
dDialect(KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.java:352)
        at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.bu
ildDialectConfigurationMap(KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.java:338)
        at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.in
it(KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.java:220)
        at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.in
it(KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.java:188)
        at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.<i
nit>(KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.java:178)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: Hi Jason, i tried to use knowledgebulder in my application to compute a charge, i tried it first in eclipse and its working fine, but when i run in weblogic server its giving above error. Thanks

Comment: you might have missed to add drools jars in the server path.